# WebClient and Gzip compression is faster?

Tags: c#, gzip, webclient

I writting an application which is using WebClient class.

Adding something like that:

```
ExC.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
```

where ExC is:

```
class ExWebClient1 : WebClient
{

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        return request;
    }
}
```

It will be a diffrence in speed when i will be using encoded response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is usually Yes.

Long answer, It depends. on the following:

1. Is the Server configured to compress responses or not.
2. Whether the request is for a dynamic or static content. (some servers do not compress dynamic content)
3. Bandwidth and latency between server and client.
4. Size of the response being returned, on small responses it wont make big a difference.

Also note, that adding the "accept-encoding" on the client side, tells the server "I understand gzip/deflate" and does not force the server to compress response.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, by adding this in header you are just letting server know that client app making request can accept zipped content. If server is capable of sending zipped response it will zip the data back after interpreting this in header. On performance If data to be fetched is huge zipping may help otherwise zipping will be small overhead which generally is negligible.